# How to define this native query return type?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jpa

In order to count the number of items added to a DB table names `url_store` I use a native query with Spring JPA
:

```
@Query(value="SELECT count(dateadded), dateadded from url_store WHERE dateadded >= ? and dateadded <= ? group by dateadded",
    nativeQuery=true)
    List<CountByDay> getAddedCountByDay(Date fromDate, Date toDate);
```

The `CountByDay` DTO object, which should be contained in the returned List:

```
import java.util.Date;

public class CountByDay {

    public CountByDay(Integer count, Date dateAdded){
        this.count = count;
        this.dateAdded = dateAdded;
    }

    public Integer getCount() {
        return count;
    }

    public void setCount(Integer count) {
        this.count = count;
    }

    private Integer count;

    public Date getDateAdded() {
        return dateAdded;
    }

    public void setDateAdded(Date dateAdded) {
        this.dateAdded = dateAdded;
    }

    private Date dateAdded;

}
```

When I invoke the `getAddedCountByDay` method I receive error:

```
org.springframework.core.convert.ConverterNotFoundException: No converter found capable of converting from type [org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery$TupleConverter$TupleBackedMap] to type [CountByDay]
    at org.springframework.core.convert.support.GenericConversionService.handleConverterNotFound(GenericConversionService.java:321) ~[spring-core-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
```

It seems I have not defined the dto `CountByDay` correctly? How to correctly define the dto in order to return a List of `CountByDay` objects ?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to try to use constructor expression JPQL as such:

```
SELECT new CountByDay(count(dateadded), dateadded) from url_store WHERE dateadded >= ? and dateadded <= ? group by dateadded
```

Answer (score 0):

I got this working by:

1.Redefine CountByDay

```
import java.util.Date;

public interface CountByDay {
Date getDateAdded();
int getCnt();
}
```

2.Update the query

```
@Query(value="SELECT count(dateadded) as cnt, dateadded as dateadded from url_store WHERE dateadded >= ? and dateadded <= ? group by dateadded",
    nativeQuery=true)
    List<CountByDay> getAddedCountByDay(Date fromDate, Date toDate);
```

This helped: [No converter found capable of converting from type to type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46083329/no-converter-found-capable-of-converting-from-type-to-type)