# No converter found capable of converting from type [java.math.BigInteger] to Entity

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I'm trying to get a list of  transactions from database and this is the error I'm facing.

> "trace": "org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException: Failed to convert from type [java.lang.Object[]] to type [com.wallet.sendmoney.entities.TransactionEntity] for value '{1, 1, null, null, KES, null, 123456, LQALVZCFJMU6, null, 2547XXXXXX3, 61234, Load wallet, null, null, null, null, null, WS322, null}'; nested exception is org.springframework.core.convert.ConverterNotFoundException: No converter found capable of converting from type [java.math.BigInteger] to type [com.wallet.sendmoney.entities.TransactionEntity]

I'm using JPA `@Query` annotation and here is my repository

```
@Repository
public interface TransactionsRepository extends JpaRepository<LoadWalletEntity, Long> {

@Query(value = "SELECT * FROM transactions_attempts WHERE mobile_number= :mobile_number", nativeQuery = true)
List<TransactionEntity> getAllByPhoneNumber(@RequestParam String mobile_number);
}
```

Here is my entity class:

```
@Entity(name = "transactions_attempts")
@Table
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class LoadWalletEntity {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;
private String currency;
@Column(name = "mobile_number")
private String mobileNumber;
private String transactionRef;
private String merchantCode;
private Integer amount;
private String networkCode;
private String reason;
private String statusCode;
private String merchantReference;
private String merchantRequestId;
private String checkoutRequestId;
private Integer resultCode;
private String resultDescription;
private String billRefNumber;
private Date transactionDate;
@Column(name = "customer_mobile")
private String customerMobile;
private String thirdPartyTransId;
}
```

What could I be missing or doing wrong here.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are trying to query a list of `TransactionEntity`

but your Repository is extends with

```
extends JpaRepository<LoadWalletEntity, Long> {
```

what's this `LoadWalletEntity`????

it should be

```
extends JpaRepository<TransactionEntity, Long> {
```

Comment: Winchester. Thanks fo pointing this out. I figured out the mistake and rectified it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62153439/14994239) please:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "transactions_attempts")
```

instead of

```
@Entity(name = "transactions_attempts")
@Table
```