# Fetch field data by joining tables in spring data JPA

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have 3 tables using spring data JPA. Table C is the mapping of Table A & B.

| Table A | Table B | Table C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| id | id | idA |
| name | tname | idB |
| code | tcode | Sname |

In front end side I want to populate a table with the values from table C. Instead of column IDs (idA & idB) I want to show the name from respective tables.
In front end I want to show as:

| Name | Type | Subtype |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Name A1 | TName B1 | Sname C1 |
| Name A2 | TName B2 | Sname C2 |

Using spring boot how can I get the values from other tables and how can perform

1. a select query
2. Using stored procedure how can I perform this operation.
   Note: I know the SQL query part not sure how to it properly in spring data jpa.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the JPA mappings take a look at [this](https://thorben-janssen.com/hibernate-tip-many-to-many-association-with-additional-attributes/).

The query to obtain what you want based on the above link would be:

```
@Query("select b.title, bp.format, p.name from Book b join b.bookPublisher bp join bp.publisher p")
```

Creating a stored procedure will differ based on the database used. Once the procedure is defined [this](https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-stored-procedures) will help you to wire JPA to call the stored procedure and obtain the results.

Comment: Do I have to create a model class for handling the output columns. eg: List<ModelClass> fetchValues();

Comment: Not a model class but a DTO with the three attributes (title, format, name). If you use a Java record.

The record:
```public record Result(String title, String format, String name) {}```

The repository query:
```@Query("select b.title, bp.format, p.name from Book b join b.bookPublisher bp join bp.publisher p")
List<Result> findAllResult();```

Comment: Getting this error org.springframework.core.convert.ConverterNotFoundException: No converter found capable of converting from type [org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery$TupleConverter$TupleBackedMap] to type [in.com.example.Practice.ResultRecord]

Comment: I was incorrect concerning records. You can only do that if your record has all the attributes of an entity. Change the record to a DTO with an all args constructor. Then change the query to ```@Query("select new in.com.example.practice.ResultRecord(b.title, bp.format, p.name) from Book b join b.bookPublisher bp join bp.publisher p")```.

Comment: Getting same error. I tried using projection based on this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46083329/no-converter-found-capable-of-converting-from-type-to-type.

Comment: Can you show us your query?

Comment: @Query(value = "SELECT name, tname, sname FROM table_c 
  right join table_a on idA = table_a.id
  right join table_b on idB = table_b.id 
  where table_c.active = 'A'", nativeQuery = true)
    List<ResultRecord> fetchData();

Comment: Can you show your ResultRecord constructor or interface?

Comment: public interface ResultRecord {
    String getName();
    String getTname();
    String getSname();
}

Comment: Try being more specific with your select: ```@Query("select table_a.name as name, table_b.tname as tname, table_c.sname as sname ...```.  Sometimes Spring Data won't perform the automatic mapping when dealing with native queries. If this is the case then you need to look for another solution.  If you use JPAQL as I mentioned above to do your query instead of a native query you will get further. ```@Query("select a.name as name, b.tname as tname, c.sname as sname from TableA a join a.b b join b.c c where c.active = 'A')``` You didn't show your entity mappings so I am guessing.